# Output of Adding StringArrayOfNumbers does not come as expected

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array of integers, check whether any number has been repeated in the array. That is, whether the array has any duplicates.

Sample Input 1

```
anyDuplicates({1,2,3,4})
```

Sample Output 1

```
false
```

Sample Input 2

```
anyDuplicates({11,22,33,44,22)
```

Sample Output 2

```
true
```

**MyApproach**

For checking whether the elements contains duplicates or not.I took too loops and checked whether the elements contains more than or equal to 2 times repeatition.If it does,i return false.else I return true.

```
public boolean anyDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    
    boolean b1=false;
    int count=0;
    int z[]=new int[arr.length];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
   {    count=0;                   //@Edit
        for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        z[i]=count;

        if(z[i]>=2) {
            b1=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(b1==true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

@Edit

## DRY RUN

When I dry run the code I got my Ans as I need to put count=0 after my for i loop.Thank you all for giving me your views.

```
Parameters                   Actual Output  Expected Output

{24,27,30}                    false         false
```

My question:Why I am not getting expected output?

Comment: You're comparing each element with itself...

Comment: Your output for the first example is `true` also.

Comment: are you allowed to use a Set? :) `return Sets.newHashSet(ary).size() != ary.length`

Comment: @brso05 I am comparing each element with itself and other elements.I am assuming that one time it occurs naturally.So if its greater or equal to 2.I am moving out of the loop and return false.

Answer (score 2):

> Update you code likewise,

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            .........
            if(z[i]>=1){...}
        }

}
```

> Your mistake is, you are first taking one value that is reside into
> a[i], and again into j-loop start with 0, so obviously a[i=0] and a[j=0] comes into comparison, which return **true** , and you will get
> wrong comparion as per your requirement,
>
> My code will work like, once value pick that is store into a[i=0...n-1],
> now not repeat a[j=1...n] again unless and untill it is revise into array

Comment: His `if` statement needs to change also...`1` instead of `2`.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, change:
      if ((i!=j) && (arr[i]==arr[j]))

more clean:

```
public boolean anyDuplicates(int[] arr)
{
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
       if ((i!=j) && (arr[i]==arr[j]))
         return true;
    }

 return false;
}
```

faster:

use a Set to put your values, and check the length against array length

```
public boolean anyDuplicates(int[] arr)
{
// => Integer[]
Integer[] array_Integer = ArrayUtils.toObject(arr);
// => Set<Integer>
Set<Integer> Set_Integer= new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array_Integer));
// => size
int sz=Set_Integer.size();

 return (sz!=arr.length);
 }
```

Comment: @guillaunme you clean code I like it.I am not checking i!=j I am doing an extra comparison.and that is why I took count >=2 to break from loop.I assumed each element exist one time.I still couldn't figure out why I am getting wrong result

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code:

1. You're comparing each element with itself.
2. You're also comparing each pair of number twice which could be reduced to once.

Here's a sample code that could achieve solutions to both these problems:

```
public boolean anyDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])
                return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```